# Select tab using button with Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, select, tabs

I have a `masterpage` and within the `Default page` I have included `jquery tabs` with a button inside the tabs.

Now If I click button it should select tab 2.

So here Is what I have done

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#<%=Nextbutton.ClientId%>").click(function () {
            $('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
        });
</script>
```

Here is my tabs with a button inside it:

```
<div id="tabs" style="position:relative;margin-left:0px;margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px;width:946px; height:432px;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Step 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Step 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Step 3</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
 <asp:Button ID="Nextbutton" class="nexttab" runat="server" Text="Go to Next tab" style="position:absolute;left:332px;top:345px;"/>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
//Some Content
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
//Some Content
</div>
```

Now my problem is whenever I click the button the page is refreshing and not selecting the tab and the same thing got worked without the master page

Can anyone point out me the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the post back just `return false`, or call the `event.preventDefault();`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%=Nextbutton.ClientId%>").click(function (event) {
            $('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Aristos-Thanks for your reply.I have just now tried using this again it refreshes the whole page.

Comment: @DotNetter Also try to load this click when the dom is ready, probably did not find it when you call it. I have add the ready() function, try it.

Comment: @Aristos-Thats the main thing there is no document.ready function now I have included it and got working.Thanks for pointing me out.

Comment: @DotNetter PreventDefault is also good and maybe better than return false, just is good to know how to prevent default, you return false and this is stop the next events.

Comment: @You're right it is good to know actually I have used return false on OnClientClick but it did not worked.So I thought something may be wrong with my code.

Comment: @DotNetter If not worked means that an exception was throw and the return false never run. The PreventDefault() on the start of the function can avoid this errors and try always to return false, even on errors.

Comment: @Aristos-Sure I will do that from next time and thanks for letting me know these all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action for the event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%=Nextbutton.ClientId%>").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Atornblad-Thanks for your reply.I have done as Aristos said and worked well!